# web.config transform not transforming

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017

I am publishing a website app to an Azure App Service. I've created a QA configuration profile and added a matching `Web.QA.config` file.  Here's the entire contents (with some redacted) of that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- For more information on using app.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->
<!-- In case configuration is not the root element, replace it with root element in source configuration file -->
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="9a...54e" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(value)" />
    <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="vuW...z3kY=" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(value)" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://....azurewebsites.net/" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(value)" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

When I publish the site to the Azure App Service using the QA profile, these values are not being transformed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're matching on `value` instead of `key`.

Use `xdt:Locator="Match(key)"`

Comment: ah! Now I feel silly. Will mark as answer when it lets me